# Waterfall - Custom Sorting in PowerBI?

Tags: reporting-services, charts, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop

I'm aware of the sorting function in waterfall, but that seems to sort the items by category and y-axis column.

[image: WaterFall Data]

What I'm hoping to do is sort non- category or y-axis column.

[image: Waterfall Power BI]

Needs to be organize by the following order:

FY 17 YTD, Revenue , Transport , Services and Delivery, HQ,  Dispatch, Duties , GL Admin

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a column to your source data and populate it with values for the preferred sort order.

Then select the column you want to custom sort and click Modeling > Sort by Column. Select the new column as the SortBy column for the existing column. The SortCategory column is used as the sort order for the Category column.

Comment: @AlfMiolan For reference, here's documentation on [Sort by Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-sort-by-column)